# How to merge multiple rows by ID and Type with additional conditions in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

[image]

I'd like to know, is there a way to merge data like what is shown in the figure in SAS or any other software?

I have several observations under the same ID. I want to merge data based on both ID and Type. For the new data highlighted in the expected table, 13 is from the length 10+3, and 54 is from the weighted average of the two observations of Type 1 under ID 1 [(10x3+67x10)/(10+3)]. I also have other data in the database that need to be cleaned like this, so I would like to know if there are codes that I can apply to bulk change the structure of the dataset to the expected one.

Comment: Please share your data as actual data instead of photographs.  Also why do you want that wide layout? Why not just leave each TYPE as its own observation?

Answer (score 0):

You can present your data using Proc TABULATE.

Example:

```
data have ;
input id type dose year ;
datalines ;
1 1 10 3
1 4 45 4
1 1 67 10
2 1 47 5
3 4 78 7
3 1 25 4
;

proc summary noprint data=have n sum mean nway ;
  class id type ;
  var year ;
  var dose / weight=year ;
  output out=smy sum(year)=sum_year mean(dose)=wmean_dose ;
run ;

data order ;
  set smy ;
  by id ;
  if first.id the seq=1;else seq+1;
run;

proc tabulate data=order;
  class id seq ;
  var wmean_dose sum_year ;
  table id, seq*(wmean_dose sum_year)*sum=' ' ;
run;
```

[image]